# Installing the joy node on Mac OSX

Tags: ros, joystick, osx, ros-groovy, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS groovy on my Mac OS 10.8.3 following the MacPorts tutorial.
I copied the joy package from the source.

```
$ rospack find joy
$ /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/joy
```

Eventually, I get:

```
$ rosdep install joy
$ ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
joy: No definition of [joystick] for OS [osx]
```

Does it mean that currently it is not possible to install the joy package on Mac?
If it is possible, I would be glad to learn which installation steps I missed.

Best regards,
Luc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62775/installing-the-joy-node-on-mac-osx/) by [Luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4899/luc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [osx_joystick](https://github.com/walchko/osx_joystick) for this at the moment. It is not entirely the same, but it shares many similarities. It at least gets the job done ;)

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0